# How to get SvelteKit forms working in Vercel/Netlify/etc

Tags: deployment, svelte, sveltekit

I'm pretty new to Svelte but it is nice and straightforward in general with this form submission I have spent hours and it is driving me crazy as it doesn't make any sense why it is not sometimes working in Vercel.

I created a separate [minimal SvelteKit project](https://github.com/service-host/vercel-test/blob/main/src/routes/%2Bpage.server.js) that submits the form to [this webhook.site endpoint](https://webhook.site/#!/0327ed0d-10b9-4dcc-bc75-dc4d605f89a2/315056e8-4e98-435d-8299-b2341292e90d/1) and it works perfectly in localhost but in [Vercel deployment](https://vercel-test-sh.vercel.app/) it works sometimes. Works once, then doesn't work three times, ten works four times in a row, then doesn't work again. Random. Sometimes Vercel gives an error, sometimes not. Here's the error:

```
[POST] /?/create
22:12:29:53
TypeError: fetch failed
    at fetch (/var/task/node_modules/undici/index.js:105:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  cause: ConnectTimeoutError: Connect Timeout Error
      at onConnectTimeout (/var/task/node_modules/undici/lib/core/connect.js:176:24)
      at /var/task/node_modules/undici/lib/core/connect.js:123:46
      at Immediate._onImmediate (/var/task/node_modules/undici/lib/core/connect.js:164:9)
      at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:471:21) {
    code: 'UND_ERR_CONNECT_TIMEOUT'
  }
}
```

Then, without doing anything I tested again and it was working like 20 times in a row. I left it like that and came back after ~1h and it was still working like 10 times per row. I was [here](https://github.com/service-host/vercel-test/commit/f9d0c73459d949569c2dee91d632266278887a2d).

Then I decided to start experimenting again and in the [next commit](https://github.com/service-host/vercel-test/commit/f9d0c73459d949569c2dee91d632266278887a2d) I removed the header authentication that isn't needed for the webhook.site but I had it there because, during the endless hours of hassling with it, I got at some point "feeling" that if the not used `HASURA_ADMIN_SECRET` ENV variable is there then it works more often. I know it is nonsense. It stopped working for good. Tested at least 20+ times with some breaks to be sure. Also tried multiple other endpoints that work brilliantly from a simple PHP script I created, from reqbin.com or from Postman. I have tried everything.

Allright, then I thought I was right - that magical `HASURA_ADMIN_SECRET` is needed so [I added it back](https://github.com/service-host/vercel-test/commit/da57938b2b0d159c4df548ea64309566531ebc8c). That didn't fix the issue. Tried dozen of times and then although I made sure I added that header auth back properly I decided also to roll back to the version where it was stable working for so long as seen [here](https://github.com/service-host/vercel-test/commit/697a2efbf83482c1ae28f755c2340a065631c867). Now even that doesn't work anymore.

I tried long ago to deploy to Netlify and CloudFare, too as I suspected it is Netlify issue but I failed to even get the site working. So I decided to spend more time on getting it working in Netlify and when [I got it working](https://netlify-test-sh.netlify.app/) I got exactly the same error as in Netlify https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rorlt.png so here's my dead end.

(I will make this post shorter once I get sorted)

Comment: I don't have an answer to how to fix the issue in Vercel but I solved it by deploying in Hetzner Cloud with ploi.io by following [these instructions](https://dev.to/mandrasch/host-sveltekit-apps-with-ssr-support-via-ploiio-on-hetzner-cloud-1cpa)

Comment: I will try that, too

Comment: I have exactly the same issue with netlify, I haven't been able to figure it out, my problem is documented here: https://answers.netlify.com/t/random-page-crash-with-runtime-unhandledpromiserejection/74925/15